# I have an exception that says this: System.NullReferenceException when adding an item to a combobox

Tags: c#

I have an exception that says this:

> System.NullReferenceException

when adding an item to a combobox with this code:

```
namespace Veterinari
{
    public partial class Diagnostico : Form
    {
        int tipo;

        public Diagnostico()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Principal prin = new Principal(tipo);
            prin.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Principal prin = new Principal(tipo);
            prin.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code and the entire error message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please format the code and also tell use which line of code gives the exception

Comment: Please add the code of combo box item adding..

Comment: That is still not the full Exception message. (does not include the stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

The `int tipo` is never instantiated.

This means that it will always be `null` until you set its value:

```
public Diagnostico()
{
    tipo = 0;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```